# How to display logcat values in the Terminal of Linux

Tags: android

Iam using the Linux platform for develoment of my application I want to display my log values in the terminal  so i have search a lot how to do any one please guide me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Ubuntu Use these simple commands

Locate to your Sdk/Platform-tools directory

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

Then run the below command

```
./adb logcat
```

Answer (score 6):

For linux use this,

```
android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools -> ./adb logcat
```

Comment: yes i got the log in the terminal , i have given path of the sdk but the part was left only the ./abd logcat thanks

Answer (score 4):

//in your terminal type **adb logcat**

```
adb logcat [ <filter-spec> ] - View device log

Usage: logcat [options] [filterspecs]
options include:
  -s              Set default filter to silent.
                  Like specifying filterspec '*:s'
  -f <filename>   Log to file. Default to stdout
  -r [<kbytes>]   Rotate log every kbytes. (16 if unspecified). Requires -f
  -n <count>      Sets max number of rotated logs to <count>, default 4
  -v <format>     Sets the log print format, where <format> is one of:

                  brief process tag thread raw time threadtime long

  -c              clear (flush) the entire log and exit
  -d              dump the log and then exit (don't block)
  -t <count>      print only the most recent <count> lines (implies -d)
  -g              get the size of the log's ring buffer and exit
  -b <buffer>     Request alternate ring buffer, 'main', 'system', 'radio'
                  or 'events'. Multiple -b parameters are allowed and the
                  results are interleaved. The default is -b main -b system.
  -B              output the log in binary
filterspecs are a series of 
  <tag>[:priority]

where <tag> is a log component tag (or * for all) and priority is:
  V    Verbose
  D    Debug
  I    Info
  W    Warn
  E    Error
  F    Fatal
  S    Silent (supress all output)

'*' means '*:d' and <tag> by itself means <tag>:v
```

Answer (score 1):

Use adb with the following flag

```
 adb logcat
```